# psycopg2 not found by django after installing in virtualenv

Tags: postgresql, django, virtualenv

I want to use postgresql with django so  did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
sudo apt-get update
workon myenv
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

And after configuring my `settings.py` correctly, I run

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

But an exception gets thrown:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2
```

The database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Check permissions in the venv -- you installed w/ sudo.

Comment: Also can you confirm that you installed `psycopg2` (and not `psycpg2`) with pip.

Comment: @xofer I did install `psycopg2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing with sudo (`sudo pip install ...`) causes the installed files to be owned by root, and Django (run without sudo) cannot read them. You can `sudo pip uninstall psycopg2` and then install without sudo. (If that doesn't work, try `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.virtualenvs/myvenv` first (assumes that's your virtualenv path).

Comment: you are my savior